# Batch exclude windows, with ver command

Tags: batch-file, goto

I want a code who jump to `:jumpto` if the windows is older than windows 8 (win 7 and older)

```
IF "windows is older than Windows 8" 6.2.9200.16384 goto jumpto'
```

I cannot formulate the correct code. Anyone who can help me out please?

I guess if i can use ver and calculate if numbers are lower than 6.2?

Comment: I have to ask why you want to do this.  Checking the OS version is almost always the wrong solution to compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('ver') DO (
    SET ver=%%a
)
SET v1=%ver:~27,1%
SET v2=%ver:~29,1%
IF %v1% LSS 6 GOTO JUMPTO
IF %v2% LSS 2 GOTO JUMPTO
ECHO doing something
PAUSE
GOTO:EOF
:JUMPTO
ECHO Windows version too old!
PAUSE
```

Comment: Is it possible for you edit this to work on windows 10 as well? Or like If windows 7 goto :test1 windows 8.1 goto :test2 windows10 goto test3

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=4,5,6 delims=[]. " %%A In ('VER') Do (
    (Set /A "_MAJ=%%A")
    (Set /A "_MIN=%%B")
    (Set /A "_BLD=%%C")
    )

echo !_MAJ!
echo !_MIN!
echo !_BLD!

endlocal
```

Note the order of the "delims=" statement.  The space must be last.